# Android App with black screen

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am working on very basic android app using cpp which shows background image (with cocos2d-x framework).

The app compiles fine and the .apk files have png files I'm using. But on launching it on Galaxy Note (Android 4.1), all it shows is black screen. I also tried adding background sound, to see if it plays, but no luck.

I also tried using dynamic libs instead of static one, but no luck. Android debugging worked partially, so I was not able to debug it successfully.

Can anyone please help, what is wrong with my setup? Sorry for long post.

My Android and Application mk files looks like this-

===================================

### ../Classes/Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := game_logic_static

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame_logic

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := AppDelegate.cpp \
                 
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) \
                        $(LOCAL_PATH)/../.. \

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := png_static_prebuilt
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += xml2_static_prebuilt
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += jpeg_static_prebuilt
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos2dx_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocosdenshion_static

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng)
$(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libxml2)
$(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libjpeg)
```

===================================

### ../jni/Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

subdirs := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../,$(addsuffix /Android.mk, \
           cocos2dx \
           CocosDenshion/android \
              \
           ))
    
subdirs += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/Android.mk $(LOCAL_PATH)/hellocpp/Android.mk

include $(subdirs)
```

---

### ../jni/hellocpp/Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := game_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp \
                   ../../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) \
                        $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../ \
                        $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../CocosDenshion/android \
                        $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../CocosDenshion/android/jni \
                        $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../CocosDenshion/include \
                        
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := png_static_prebuilt
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += xml2_static_prebuilt
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += jpeg_static_prebuilt
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += curl_static_prebuilt
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := game_logic_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos2dx_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocosdenshion_static
            
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libcurl)
$(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libpng)
$(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libxml2)
$(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libjpeg)
```

---

### ../jni/Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti
APP_MODULES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static game_logic_static game_shared
```

===================================

If you have any cleanup suggestions for duplicates in those mk files, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: which cocos2d-x version are you using?

Comment: I am using latest 2.0 version. I solved the problem...the main.java file was not latest, I was using it from previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided correct resource name used in background sprite ?

You can also check if the resource you are accessing is present in your assets or not ?